# Can Count(*) ever return null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result)

Is it possible in any scenario for the Count() function to return NULL?

Comment: Discussed previously [Does COUNT(*) always return a result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result). never NULL: zero or no result at all

Comment: Here's an interesting related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115710/count-returns-null)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it will only return a zero (or non-zero) result.  SqlServer will not return null.

Comment: Surely you mean "or non-zero and non-null"??

Comment: @cyberwiki - good point :-)  Would be quite pointless if it always returned zero!

Comment: There are some cases where there is no result returned (if your select has a `GROUP BY` and there is no group). Depending on how you use your query, for instance if you use some ORM, this no result might be mapped to a `null`.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997(v=SQL.90).aspx), no.

That said:

> For return values greater than 2^31-1, COUNT produces an error. Use COUNT_BIG instead.

Answer (score 4):

No.

This will be 0

```
select count(*)
where 0=1
```

This will be 1

```
select count(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

No it returns a zero if the table does not have any records in the table

Answer (score 1):

No. If  the table or specific field being counted are empty it will return zero.