# Return 1 instead of 0 when Count(*) result is Null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, count

My code from SQL Server:

```
SELECT ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO, ISNULL(count(ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO), 0) as how_many
 from ESTAGIO
 left join ESTAGIARIO
 on ESTAGIARIO.SK_ESTAGIO = ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO
 group by
    ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO
```

When "ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO" doesn't exist in the table "ESTAGIARIO" it returns 1 instead of 0, I already tried to use ISNULL(), NULLIF() and COALESCE() and still couldn't find the problem that is making the query above returning 1 when it should be 0.

Comment: count() will return 0..n never NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are counting the wrong field. Do it like this, taking the field from the outer joined table `ESTAGIARIO` (not from `ESTAGIO`):

```
SELECT ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO, Count(ESTAGIARIO.SK_ESTAGIO) as how_many
 from ESTAGIO
 left join ESTAGIARIO
 on ESTAGIARIO.SK_ESTAGIO = ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO
 group by
    ESTAGIO.SK_ESTAGIO
```

BTW, [`count` can never return `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970314/can-count-ever-return-null).

Comment: Oh man.. thanks for the fast and usefull answer, it was so obvious and i couldn't see it xD thanks.