# SQL Query to count users with left join of 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count the number of users who are inactive in 1 of our 2 applications.

I have 2 tables - the `Users` table and the `User_Applications` table, which has rows containing a user id, an application id, and a boolean whether they are active or inactive.

If a user has been given access to an application, a row is added to User_Applications. So, if they've been given access to App A and App B, there are 2 rows. If they've been given access only to App A, there is only 1 row.

It is assumed that if no record exists in `User_Applications` regarding App B, then the user is inactive. If no records exist at all for a user in User_Applications, they are inactive in both App A and App B.

Imagine a join like this:

```
| user_id | app_id | active |  
|---------|--------|--------|  
| 1       | 'A'    | false  |  
| 1       | 'B'    | true   |  
| 2       | null   | null   |  
| 3       | 'B'    | true   |
```

If I'm counting the number of users who are inactive in A, user 1, 2, and 3 are all inactive. However, my SQL script only counts users like 1 and 2. It doesn't count users like 3. How do I include users like #3 in my query?

I wrote this SQL script to count the number of inactive users in App A:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN User_Applications s on u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE (s.app_id = 'A' OR s.app_id IS NULL)
AND (s.active = false OR s.active IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the code below what you're looking for?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN User_Applications s on u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE (s.app_id = 'A' OR s.app_id = 'B' OR s.app_id IS NULL) AND (s.active = false OR s.active IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional `COUNT()` and instead try to count how many active app has each user. Then you count who doesn't have 2 active apps

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN s.active THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN User_Applications s 
      ON u.user_id = s.user_id
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN s.active THEN 1 END) < 2
) T
```

I add `ELSE NULL` but is the default value for `ELSE`, so also work if you don't add it

`COUNT()` doesn't count null. So if user doesn't have permission for the app, the `left join` return `null` and wont count, if user isn't active the CASE will also return null and wont count

So you will found those who doesnt have 2 active apps.

Answer (score 0):

Count users with max 1 active App from the ('A' , 'B') list

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) nActive
   FROM User_Applications 
   WHERE app_id IN ('A' , 'B') AND active
   GROUP BY user_id 
) s on u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE (s.nActive <= 1 OR s.nActive IS NULL)
```

Comment: Should check for `<= 1` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970314/can-count-ever-return-null